# SQL Check constraint againt 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I need to add a check constraint and requires a value to be 0 if another value is less than 3.
ok so far I got an answer but it is not installing into my DB. Here si a my test table and the data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(Col1 INT, Col2 INT);

insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 5
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 1, 5
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 3
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 11
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 4
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 145
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 10
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 1
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 6
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 6
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 2
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 5
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 1, 3
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 10
insert into YourTable (Col1,Col2) SELECT 0, 10


ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT TestConstraint 
CHECK ((Col1 = 0 AND Col2 <= 3) OR Col2 > 3)
```

Comment: So what is the problem which you are facing when you run this query?

Comment: The constraint solution that was answered does not work. I provided some test data. Maybe I have a setting in the database different than is required for that version of the constraint to install.

Comment: What does it mean that the constraint doesn't work?, can you elaborate?

Comment: IF run the statements in the question, does the constraint install? for me it does not

Comment: Again, what do you mean by that?. Does it throw an error?, what happens?

Comment: Yes. I get the error: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "TestConstraint". The conflict occurred in database "DATABASE", table "dbo.YourTable".   The data in the example is correct.

Comment: You seem to be confused as to what a constraint does. It **doesn't** change data that already exists, so if you have values that don't pass the check, then it fails to create the constraint, is that simple

Comment: I know. I want it to prevent incorrect data from getting inserted or updated in this table.the data I provided is correct. the constraint is wrong. I had some other advice about making a trigger and making the insert fail. would that be a better option for what I am trying to do?

Comment: @Lamak - The question states "less than 3". Your constraint is `<=`. So it fails the row `(1, 3)`

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, I was about to say that in this comment. Joe just need to change the constraint to `CHECK ((Col1 = 0 AND Col2 < 3) OR Col2 >= 3)` to make it work with his data

Comment: wow that was a subtle change. Thanks for finding the missing piece, @MartinSmith.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(Col1 INT, Col2 INT);

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT TestConstraint 
CHECK ((Col1 = 0 AND Col2 <= 3) OR Col2 > 3);
```